# How can I convert a reference type to a value type?

Tags: c++, c++11, reference, decltype

I'm trying to move some code to templates using the new `decltype` keyword, but when used with dereferenced pointers, it produces reference type. SSCCE:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    int a = 42;
    int *p = &a;
    std::cout << std::numeric_limits<decltype(a)>::max() << '\n';
    std::cout << std::numeric_limits<decltype(*p)>::max() << '\n';
}
```

The first `numeric_limits` works, but the second throws a `value-initialization of reference type 'int&'` compile error. How do I get a value type from a pointer to that type?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use [`std::remove_reference`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/remove_reference) to make it a non-reference type:

```
std::numeric_limits<
    std::remove_reference<decltype(*p)>::type
>::max();
```

[<kbd>Live demo</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/532e346eaa96eb76)

or:

```
std::numeric_limits<
    std::remove_reference_t<decltype(*p)>
>::max();
```

for something slightly less verbose.

Answer (score 7):

If you are going from a pointer to the pointed-to type, why bother dereferencing it at all? Just, well, remove the pointer:

```
std::cout << std::numeric_limits<std::remove_pointer_t<decltype(p)>>::max() << '\n';
// or std::remove_pointer<decltype(p)>::type pre-C++14
```

Comment: with `::type` if OP doesn't have C++14

Answer (score 5):

You want to remove reference as well as potentially `const`ness I'd guess, so you'd use

```
std::numeric_limits<std::decay_t<decltype(*p)>>::max()
```

Comment: Why would he want to remove `const`ness exactly? `std::numeric_limits` [works](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1b9d309e4f8c8453) perfectly fine with `const T` types.